# How to point to Wordpress blog from firebase hosting subdirectory

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

We are using firebase to host our react js application.

Also, we have a WordPress blog, hosted on Siteground.

We need to access the blog from `[Domain]/blog`

Firebase offers hosting configuration object and you can use rewrite rules to define source and destination.
But unfortunately, it just lets you add a local path in Destination, not external IP or Domain.

We need something like this in firebase hosting config object:

```
      "hosting": {
        // ...

        // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
        "rewrites": [ {
          "source": "/blog",
          "destination": "[SERVER IP / CUSTOM"
        } ]
      }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You will probably want to try a **redirect** instead of a rewrite.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects

Comment: Can we use an IP address in the destination with redirect property, please? @DougStevenson

Comment: I don't know.  Try it.

Comment: Looking for an answer to this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have the exact same question. Siteground blog, Firebase app.